# Div with display set to none still registering click events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have attempted to make a dropdown menu using pure HTML, CSS, and js, yet I have encountered a problem. When the menu is closed and i click close below it, it thinks I'm clicking the options inside of it, i couldn't really figure out what causes this as when the menu is closed, my js script removes the `active` class which makes them only have the `tag` class which sets their visibility to hidden and their display to none.

View my snippet and it's code below or this codepen: https://codepen.io/troopek/pen/dyqQNVa

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const optionMenu = document.querySelector(".select-wrapper");
  const selectButton = optionMenu.querySelector(".select-button");
  const options = optionMenu.querySelectorAll(".option");
  const selectButtonText = optionMenu.querySelector(".select-button-text");

  selectButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
    optionMenu.classList.toggle("active")
  );

  options.forEach((option) => {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let selectedOption = option.querySelector(".option-text").innerText;
      selectButtonText.innerText = selectedOption;

      optionMenu.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (!optionMenu.contains(event.target)) {
      optionMenu.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #e3f2fd;
}

.select-wrapper {
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.select-wrapper .select-button {
  display: flex;
  height: 55px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.select-wrapper .options {
  position: absolute;
  width: 330px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 295px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 0.35s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.35s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.select-wrapper .options .option {
  display: flex;
  height: 55px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
}
.select-wrapper .options .option:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.select-wrapper .options .option i {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.select-wrapper .options .option .option-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
}

.select-button i {
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.select-wrapper.active .select-button i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.select-wrapper.active .options {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css" />
  <script src="/src/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <div class="select-button">
      <div class="select-button-text">Select an option</div>
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>

    <ul class="options">
      <div class="option">
        <p class="option-text">Margin</p>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <p class="option-text">Test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <p class="option-text">Fees</p>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When inspecting the html we can see that the `ul` is still in the DOM and clickable:

[image]

You are toggling the `active` class on the wrapping `div` which contains the "Select an option" input. You can fix this by toggling `display:none` on the `ul.options` as well